# lightbox background effect

Tags: jquery

I'm just starting to learn jQuery and I'm not sure how to enable a background effect similar to a lightbox.

I want my `<div>` (registration wizard) to appear at 100% opacity and I'd like everything else behind it to be somewhere around 50% opacity and non-clickable.

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how:

```
$('<div id="overlay" />').css({
   position:'fixed'
 , width: '100%'
 , height : '100%'
 , opacity : 0.6
 , background: '#000'
 , zIndex:9999
 , top: 0
 , left: 0
}).appendTo(document.body);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsdo.it/blaster/dLI8)

You may put above code in a function and call it whenever you need that overlay. To remove it when you don't need it, you would do:

```
$('#overlay').remove();
```

---

FYI, you can also put above styles in CSS in a class and then use jQuery's `addClass` to `body` whenever you need it and `removeClass` when you want to remove it.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa Copy-pasting the code into the JS console doesn't give my syntax errors.

Comment: If I apply that to my page (on `#container`) everything, including the `<div>` I want 100% is affected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Paul: I forgot to add `zIndex` and `top` and `left`, updated in answer now, try with that.